# Java EE cluster changes the JSESSIONID on each request

Tags: jakarta-ee, cluster-computing, weblogic-10.x, jsessionid

I installed a two-node Weblogic 10.3.6 cluster. The two nodes are on the same computer as the browser, only the ports are different.

No matter what Java app I write and deploy, if I send requests altering the nodes they always send a changed JSESSIONID back. If I send the requests to only one of the nodes the JSESSIONID never changes.

Is this normal or is my cluster misconfigured somehow?

Answer (score 0):

a bit late to be answering this but it sounds very like your application is not replicated across the cluster.  This requires configuration in the app specific weblogic.xml and the weblogic cluster itself.